# How to convert an array T[] to V[] when V is an attribute object in T

Tags: java, arrays, performance, iteration

A simple way of doing so is to iterate over the array T[] and assign its field of type V and fill the new array.
But, is there a more efficient/elegant way (possibly a built-in feature in Java)?

Edit:
 the code I tried:

```
Locale[] locs = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
String[] coutries = new String[locs.length] ;
for (int i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
    coutries[i] = locs[i].getDisplayCountry();
}
```

Edit2:
It seems that using the map operation on streams is faster for a small array of at around 200 elements, here is the second approach:

```
coutries = Arrays.stream(locs).map(Locale -> Locale.getDisplayCountry()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please show us some code and describe properly what you want to do (e.g. clone the array or whatever the outcome should be)

Comment: I tried what I already said, re-read my question, and people out there please down vote for a reason.

Comment: In most languages you'd do a `map` operation using a closure. I'm not sure this is possible in Java.

Comment: Or just try write some recursive function it will work more fast!!!!

Comment: @VostanAzatyan Arguments for recursive functions are generally for clarity, not performance reasons. Set up/tear down of functions is considerably slower than loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you can use the [`map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operation on [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
V[] arr = Arrays.stream(arrayOfTypeT).map(t -> t.v).toArray(V[]::new);
```

or even better (if good encapsulation)

```
V[] arr = Arrays.stream(arrayOfTypeT).map(T::getV).toArray(V[]::new);
```

---

So here's the benchmark (note that I'm not a JMH guru):

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
public class Benchmark {   

    static Integer[] ints = IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

    public static void main(String... args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
        .include(".*" + Benchmark.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
        .forks(1)
        .warmupIterations(20)
        .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void standardForLoop() {
        final String[] arr = new String[ints.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = String.valueOf(ints[i]);
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void forEachLoop() {
        final String[] arr = new String[ints.length];
        for (int i : ints) {
            arr[i] = String.valueOf(i);
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void streamMapOperation() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String[] arr = Arrays.stream(ints).map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void streamParallelMapOperation() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String[] arr = Arrays.stream(ints).parallel().map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    }    
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark                                Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
b.Benchmark.forEachLoop                  avgt        20       58,455        2,359    ms/op
b.Benchmark.standardForLoop              avgt        20       59,214        2,415    ms/op
b.Benchmark.streamMapOperation           avgt        20       62,877        2,887    ms/op
b.Benchmark.streamParallelMapOperation   avgt        20       40,171        6,456    ms/op
```

As you can see, for huge data-set there is no big difference between a standard loop and the stream approach. But with the stream approach, you can easily call `parallel()`, which makes the computations slightly more efficient (of course you could write your own multithreaded utility to do this, but that would require a bit of work on your side).

Note that `parallel()` can be less efficient for small data set, due to the fact of threads setup, synchronization, etc. So don't do premature optimization. Measure first your code and if there is really a performance problem, try to investigate where and why.

Comment: Urgh. Oracle got to look at the way many many other languages perform this sort of task and this syntactical monstrosity is the way they chose to do it?

Comment: @ZouZou: Of course, if you're going to include the `parallel` numbers, you should include numbers for multi-threaded loops. But the non-`parallel` numbers aren't bad at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The spirit of the benchmark was to show that there are no differences between the sequential stream approach and the standard loop. Of course you're right that multi- threaded loops should give the same results but IMO this is far more work and code to write that invoking `parallel()` on the Stream.

Comment: @ZouZou: Well, it depends. If you already have utility classes that break up the work, it isn't. Which is, of course, exactly what `parallel` is: A pre-written utility that breaks up the work for you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But you would have to write thoses classes while this already implemented in the Stream API. Kind of reinventing the wheel :-)

Comment: @ZouZou: Not if you'd *already* invented it. I'm just trying to compare apples with apples. (And the streams come off very well in that comparison, even leaving `parallel` aside.) For 20 years, we didn't have the stream classes, and people built up their own utilities. Oh, forgot to say: Thank you for the benchmark code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For people who already have this utilities it's fine. I just show the way using the standard Stream API. If you have one I would happily add it to the benchmark !

Comment: @ZouZou: No, haven't needed to parallel-ize an array so far.